# Locating a pdf of certain paper

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

One of the references in the book Opera de Cribro by Friedlander and Iwaniec is:

J. Friedlander and H. Iwaniec, A polynomial divisor problem, J. Reine Angew. Math. 601 (2006),
109-137

Does anybody know where I can find a pdf of the above paper?

Comment: Depends on what journal access you have. If you're at a university, just try their library.

Comment: I don't have access to any journal or library with this paper.